# how to avoid duplicates in hive query

Tags: sql, hive, case, hiveql

I have two tables:

**table1**

```
the_date | my_id |

02/03/2021,123
02/03/2021, 1234
02/03/2021, 12345
```

**table2**

```
the_date | my_id |seq | txt
02/03/2021, 1234, 1 , 'OK'
02/03/2021, 12345, 1, 'OK'
02/03/2021, 12345, 2, 'HELLO HI THERE'
02/03/2021, 123456, 1, 'Ok'
```

**Here is my code:**

```
WITH AB AS (
SELECT  A1.my_id
FROM DB1.table1 A1 , DB1.MSG_REC A2  WHERE
A1.my_id=A2.my_id
),
BC AS (
SELECT  AB.the_date
COUNT ( DISTINCT (CASE WHEN (TXT like '%OK%') THEN AB.my_id ELSE NULL END )) AS
CASE1 ,
COUNT ( DISTINCT (CASE WHEN (TXT like '%HELLO HI THERE%') THEN AB.my_id ELSE NULL END )) AS
CASE2
FROM AB left JOIN DB1.my_id BC ON AB.my_id =BC.my_id
```

The issue that stems from above is I am looping over the value '12345' twice because it satisfies both of the case statements.

That causes data duplicates when capturing metrics of the counts. Is there a way to  execute the first case and then perform the second case but exclude looping any of the "my_id' records from the first case.

**So for example, when it is time to run the above script and the first case executes, it will pick up the below records and the count would be 3**

```
 02/03/2021, 1234, 1 , 'OK'
  02/03/2021, 12345, 1, 'OK'
 02/03/2021, 123456, 1, 'Ok
```

**The second case should only be looping through the below records and the count would be only 1**

```
 02/03/2021, 12345, 2, 'HELLO HI THERE'
```

CASE1 would be 4 and CASE2 would by 2 if I don't create a condition to circumvent this issue. Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: This query needs some work - 1)  column "the_date" is not qualified in common table expression (cte) AB  ,  2) cte BC needs a "group by" clause on the phantom column 
 the_date (see 1)  - 3) cte BC needs to be closed - 4) the statement needs to end with a select * from BC 5) In cte AB - is "table2" meant to be MSG_REC ?

Answer (score 1):

Assign case to each your ID before DISTINCT aggregation . After that do distinct aggregation, in such way you will eliminate same IDs counted in different cases. See comments in the code:

```
select --do final distinct aggregation
      count(distinct (case when assigned_case='CASE1' then my_id else null end ) ) as CASE1,
      count(distinct (case when assigned_case='CASE2' then my_id else null end ) ) as CASE2
from 
(
select my_id
       --assign single CASE to all rows with the same id based on some logic:
        case when case1_flag = 1 then 'CASE1' 
            when case1_flag = 1 then 'CASE2'
           else NULL
        end as assigned_case
from
(--calculate all CASE flags for each ID 
select AB.my_id, 
       max(CASE WHEN (TXT like '%OK%') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)  over (partition by AB.my_id) as case1_flag
       max(CASE WHEN (TXT like '%HELLO HI THERE%') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)  over (partition by AB.my_id) as case2_flag
from ...
) s
) s
```